# SQL server 2008 select in

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this basic consult is sql, but is giving me this error in management studio:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Oficios_dev2].[dbo].[doc].[typecdocumentdet] as [C] 
where [C].[TypeCDocument] in (select [Oficios_dev2].[dbo].[doc].[TypeCDocument] as [D] 
                              where [D].[Id] = '1')
```

Error

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "D.Id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "Oficios_dev2.dbo.doc.TypeCDocument" could not be bound.
```

I have no idea why , anyone? Thanks

EDIT: New query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Oficios_dev2].[dbo].[doc] as [C] where [C].[TypeCDocument]  in (select [Oficios_dev2].[dbo].[doc] from [Oficios_dev2].[dbo].[doc] as [D] where [D].[Id] = '1')
```

this gives me less errors still 1

```
The multi-part identifier "Oficios_dev2.dbo.doc" could not be bound.
```

Comment: The inner select misses a field list and a `from`.

Comment: Is `Oficios_dev2` a remote server?  If yes, then it needs to be added as a linked server. Check `select * from sys.servers` to see if it already added as a linked server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test the inner query that you're using. It should be able to run independently of the full query. In this example, the inner query does not have the correct` syntax.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Oficios_dev2].[dbo].[typecdocumentdet] as [C] 
where [C].[TypeCDocument] in (select [TypeCDocument]
                              from [Oficios_dev2].[dbo].[doc] as [D] 
                              where [D].[Id] = '1')
```

Note: I'm assuming that `[doc]` is the name of the table you want to the inner query to run on, and the `[TypeCDocument]` is the column you want to select for use by the `IN` expression list.

Answer (score 4):

the inner query is not formatted correctly:

you have:

```
(select [Oficios_dev2].[dbo].[doc].[TypeCDocument] as [D] where [D].[Id] = '1')
```

should by something like this:

```
(select TypeCDocument FROM [Oficios_dev2].[dbo].[doc] as [D] where [D].[Id] = '1')
```

Comment: I changed to this now it gives me this: Could not find server 'Oficios_dev2' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Comment: the suggested text was corrected by @Gordon ... did you try it before or after his edit ?

Comment: If `Oficios_dev2` is a remote server then it needs to be added as a linked server.  Check `select * from sys.servers` to see if the server is setup as a remote server and that the name is spelled correctly. If it's not setup as a remote server you will need to add it with the sp_addlinkedserver stored procedure.

Comment: Yea, it isn't is local. (: